# Multiple class use in same class file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

in this below code we use extends 3rd party module tranactionservice but if class is not exist only class declared but the coding standard giving error severity **Each class must be in a file by itself**

```
namespace Test\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Model\TransactionService;
if (class_exists(TransactionService::class)) {
    class Service extends TransactionService
    {
    }
}else{
    class Service 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the coding standard that is giving an error, along with your class file, so we can better understand?

Comment: Each class must be in a file by itself - this error is coming in codesniffer magento2 – 
 @Msquare

Answer (score 0):

To adhere to Magento 2 coding standards, you should separate these classes into their own files. For example:

Service.php

namespace Test\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Model\TransactionService;

if (class_exists(TransactionService::class)) {
class Service extends TransactionService
{
}
} else {
class Service
{
}
}

Comment: same code only u given not correct